# Exception flood using .await() when Single throws exception

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm creating integration tests for my application using Spek. I have a set of `Provider`s to test and each one makes a request and parses a response.

```
describe("Providers")
{
    for(provider in providers)
    {
        on("Provider: $providerName")
        {
            try
            {
                //...
                val responsePromise = when (provider)
                {
                    is HtmlProvider -> connectionService.reactiveGetForHtml(connectionRequest)
                    is JsonProvider<*> -> connectionService.reactiveGetForJson(connectionRequest, provider.getJsonClass())
                    else -> throw IllegalStateException("Provider must be either Html or JSON")
                }

                val response = runBlocking { responsePromise.await() }
```

Both `connectionService.reactiveGetForHtml()` `reactiveGetForJson()` return a RxJava2's `SingleSource`.

The problem: one of `Provider`s throws a bunch of exceptions (it has to parse a big JSON file and due to problems with data model Jackson throws huge number of exceptions). This is fine, test are designed to handle and report such errors. In this case, problematic `Provider` fails its own test with a Jackson exception. But, when runner executes remaining test cases, strange things happen. All next `Provider`s' tests fail because of the same exceptions. `runBlocking` keeps throwing exceptions from faulty `Provider` on and on, no matter what `responsePromise` is. Don't know if this is a bug or some strange behaviour of .await(), but I don't hava any idea how to overcome this.
All test cases of `Provider`s that don't throw multiple exceptions run well and report their own errors, but after executing that faulty `Provider` everything fails. It's not the case of this exact `Provider`, if I removed this particular test case, other `Provider`s that thrown multiple exceptions caused simiar problem.

Comment: It looks like this: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/691

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik tried wrapping in `supervisorScope` - no difference